# Security Invalid key exception

Tags: java, encryption, glassfish

I am having a problem with encryption and I know almost nothing about it. Everything used to work fine, but there were some changes into the app encryption and now when I try to log in I get this message as a popup message in my browser:

> Not an ARCFOUR key: md5
>   class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException

And in my glassfish server I get something like this:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Not an ARCFOUR key: md5
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.ARCFOURCipher.getEncodedKey(ARCFOURCipher.java:195)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.ARCFOURCipher.engineGetKeySize(ARCFOURCipher.java:259)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1062)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1020)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:796)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166)
```

And my app fail to retrieve data from my Oracle database.

Anyone had this problem(error)?

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is that the value of the key should be derived using MD5, but that either a string containing `"MD5"` is passed, or that an MD5 object instance is not evaluated to a byte array. Either one of them would indicate a serious issue. Looking at the source code of `ARCFOURCipher` would be required. The bug database may also help.

Comment: I guess it would be sufficient if the OP updates the question with the code which is using the `Cipher` class :)